# C++ app performance varies when using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a C++ app with 2 threads. The app displays a gauge on the screen, with an indicator that rotates based on an angle received via UDP socket. My problem is that the indicator should be rotating at a constant rate but it behaves like time slows down at times, and it also fast-forwards to catch up quickly at other times, with some pauses intermittently.

Each frame, the display (main) thread guards a copy of the angle from the UDP thread. The UDP thread also guards writing to the shared variable. I use a Windows CriticalSection object to guard the 'communication' between threads. The UDP packet is received at approximately the same rate as the display update. I am using Windows 7, 64 bit, with a 4-core processor.

I am using a separate python app to broadcast the UDP packet. I use the python function, time.sleep, to keep the broadcast at a constant rate.

Why does the application slow down?
Why does the application seem to fast-forward instead of snapping to the latest angle?
What is the proper fix?

**EDIT:** I am not 100% sure all angle values are remembered when the app seems to 'fast forward'. The app is snapping to some value (not sure if it is the 'latest') at times.

**EDIT 2**: per request, some code.

```
void App::udp_update(DWORD thread_id)
{
  Packet p;
  _socket.recv(p); // edit: blocks until transmission is received

  {
    Locker lock(_cs);
    _packet = p;
  }
}

void App::main_update()
{
  float angle_copy = 0.f;

  {
    Locker lock(_cs);
    angle_copy = _packet.angle;
  }

  draw(angle_copy); // edit: blocks until monitor refreshes
}
```

**Thread.h**

```
class CS
{
private:
  friend Locker;

  CRITICAL_SECTION _handle;

  void _lock();
  void _unlock();

  // not implemented by design
  CS(CS&);
  CS& operator=(const CS&);

public:
  CS();
  ~CS();
};


class Locker
{
private:
  CS& _cs;

  // not implemented by design
  Locker();
  Locker(const Locker&);
  Locker& operator=(const Locker&);

public:
  Locker(CS& c)
    : _cs(c)
  {
    _cs._lock();
  }

  ~Locker()
  {
    _cs._unlock();
  }
};



class Win32ThreadPolicy
{
public:
  typedef Functor<void,TYPELIST_1(DWORD)> Callback;

private:
  Callback _callback;

  //SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR _sec_descr;
  //SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES _sec_attrib;
  HANDLE _handle;
  //DWORD _exitValue;

#ifdef USE_BEGIN_API
  unsigned int _id;
#else // USE_BEGIN_API
  DWORD _id;
#endif // USE_BEGIN_API

  /*volatile*/ bool _is_joined;

#ifdef USE_BEGIN_API
  static unsigned int WINAPI ThreadProc( void* lpParameter );
#else // USE_BEGIN_API
  static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParameter );
#endif // USE_BEGIN_API

  DWORD _run();
  void _join();

  // not implemented by design
  Win32ThreadPolicy();
  Win32ThreadPolicy(const Win32ThreadPolicy&);
  Win32ThreadPolicy& operator=(const Win32ThreadPolicy&);

public:
  Win32ThreadPolicy(Callback& func);
  ~Win32ThreadPolicy();

  void Spawn();
  void Join();
};

/// helps to manage parallel operations.
/// attempts to mimic the C++11 std::thread interface, but also passes the thread ID.
class Thread
{
public:
  typedef Functor<void,TYPELIST_1(DWORD)> Callback;
  typedef Win32ThreadPolicy PlatformPolicy;

private:
  PlatformPolicy _platform;

  /// not implemented by design
  Thread();
  Thread(const Thread&);
  Thread& operator=(const Thread&);

public:
  /// begins parallel execution of the parameter, func.
  /// \param func, the function object to be executed.
  Thread(Callback& func)
    : _platform(func)
  {
    _platform.Spawn();
  }

  /// stops parallel execution and joins with main thread.
  ~Thread()
  {
    _platform.Join();
  }
};
```

**Thread.cpp**

```
#include "Thread.h"

void CS::_lock()
{
  ::EnterCriticalSection( &_handle );
}

void CS::_unlock()
{
  ::LeaveCriticalSection( &_handle );
}

CS::CS()
  : _handle()
{
  ::memset( &_handle, 0, sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION) );

  ::InitializeCriticalSection( &_handle );
}

CS::~CS()
{
  ::DeleteCriticalSection( &_handle );
}


Win32ThreadPolicy::Win32ThreadPolicy(Callback& func)
  : _handle(NULL)
    //, _sec_descr()
    //, _sec_attrib()
  , _id(0)
  , _is_joined(true)
  , _callback(func)
{
}

void Win32ThreadPolicy::Spawn()
{
  // for an example of managing descriptors, see:
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  //BOOL success_descr = ::InitializeSecurityDescriptor( &_sec_descr, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION );

  //TODO: do we want to start with CREATE_SUSPENDED ?

  // TODO: wrap this with exception handling
#ifdef USE_BEGIN_END
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
  _handle = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &Thread::ThreadProc, this, 0, &_id );
#else // USE_BEGIN_END
  _handle = ::CreateThread( NULL, 0, &Win32ThreadPolicy::ThreadProc, this, 0, &_id );
#endif // USE_BEGIN_END
}

void Win32ThreadPolicy::_join()
{
  // signal that the thread should complete
  _is_joined = true;

  // maybe ::WFSO is not the best solution.
  // "Except that WaitForSingleObject and its big brother WaitForMultipleObjects are dangerous.
  // The basic problem is that these calls can cause deadlocks,
  // if you ever call them from a thread that has its own message loop and windows."
  // http://marc.durdin.net/2012/08/waitforsingleobject-why-you-should-never-use-it/
  //
  // He advises to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects instead:
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  DWORD result = ::WaitForSingleObject( _handle, INFINITE );

  // _handle must have THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION security access enabled to use the following:
  //DWORD exitCode = 0;
  //BOOL success = ::GetExitCodeThread( _handle, &_exitValue );
}

Win32ThreadPolicy::~Win32ThreadPolicy()
{
}

void Win32ThreadPolicy::Join()
{
  if( !_is_joined )
    {
      _join();
    }

  // this example shows that it is correct to pass the handle returned by CreateThread
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  ::CloseHandle( _handle );

  _handle = NULL;
}

DWORD Win32ThreadPolicy::_run()
{
  // TODO: do we need to make sure _id has been assigned?

  while( !_is_joined )
    {
      _callback(_id);
      ::Sleep(0);
    }

  // TODO: what should we return?
  return 0;
}

#ifdef USE_BEGIN_END
unsigned int WINAPI Thread::ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParameter )
#else // USE_BEGIN_END
  DWORD WINAPI Win32ThreadPolicy::ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParameter )
#endif // USE_BEGIN_END
{
  Win32ThreadPolicy* tptr = static_cast<Win32ThreadPolicy*>( lpParameter );
  tptr->_is_joined = false;

  // when this function (ThreadProc) returns, ::ExitThread is used to terminate the thread with an "implicit" call.
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  return tptr->_run();
}
```

Comment: Difficult to answer with seeing actual code. However it Sounds like something is blocking your rendering thread. I would try to scope down the issue by performing some profiling on your threads. Also I read that you receive an angle via UDP socket? How do you achieve a constant rotation speed? I expect that the bitrate will not always be constant.

Comment: thread and guard code:
http://pastebin.com/LrDcSQKS
http://pastebin.com/MLDbNTjk

Comment: please put as much code as possible directly in your question!

Comment: You don't show how you are using these with the sockets, which, I guess, is where the problem lies: I imagine that your network thread is receiving/handling messages in bulk, and then passing them all at once to the display thread. Most probably all you have to do is to put a small wait time on socket polling, and have the display thread yield execution back as often as possible to smooth their interactions down.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra code. I did not want to muddy the discussion.

  - Socket::recv() blocks until a packet is received.
  - App::display() blocks until monitor refreshes.

Comment: @didierc I tried your suggestion, adding Sleep to my display thread (and removing blocking behavior from display thread). It successfully smoothed out the behavior - thanks! I am worried adding Sleep in my UDP thread will miss transmissions. I wish I could avoid Sleep in either thread. Is that possible? Sleeping in my display thread may cause an extra frame of delay.

I do not know what you mean by 'in bulk'. My server sends one packet at a time, and my client consumes one packet at a time. The latter is visible in App code above.

Comment: I don't know at what rate you're sending packets, so I might very well be wrong, but from the description of the problem, the UDP thread is processing several packets at once. I don't think you need to put the UDP thread to sleep, actually you should not. It should be polling all the time on the socket. I guess you don't need to shorten the polling time after all. You should try out different combinations and keep the one that works best for your setup (though the correct timings might be different on another system - eg, single vs many core).

Comment: @didierc thanks for the extra input. I'm glad you agree the UDP thread should not Sleep. The motivation for avoiding Sleep in the display thread is so I can block until the monitor refreshes, avoiding visual 'tearing'. I would like a solution in which the display is not visually impacted by the rate the packets are sent. Currently, I am sending at approximately the same rate as the display update. (which is what I meant to imply  in original post, 'The UDP packet is received at approximately the same rate as the display update'.)

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't pick that info on first read. Well, you're looking for a response time at the millisecond resolution. If your apps are on a clean and fast network, you shouldn't have a problem to get notified of packets at that frequency, but if your machine is somewhat busy, I would expect packets to be lumped together from time to time. Perhaps going with something like async IO would help keeping the rate steady. Secondly, for one to one communication, you don't need a mutex, a queue should be OK (look it up there are ways to make that work without locks).

Comment: Uhhh, I wonder why I thought you were reading packets in bulk, since you can limit that directly by giving a read buffer of exactly one packet lengthm..OK, I think it should work better simply by getting rid of that CS and making sure you can queue up messages between threads. Then you want display thread to take care of exactly one packet per frame, I guess you've got that cleared by having it usleep in between frames (or do something else).

Comment: @didierc if I go with a queue, is it necessary to avoid the lock? The code seems straightforward if I use a lock/CS to guard access to the std::queue. Will my app suffer the same problem? Does that imply that the lock is the problem?

Comment: In your current implementation, your threads are like interlocked clockwork wheels. They must turn at the same pace, and if one is being slowed down, the other one has to follow suit. By getting rid of the lock, you make each of them more resilient to the other thread's speed of execution, and you may even include some logic to handle the case when a the other guy skips a beat, or if it is getting late.

Comment: Note that my experience with windows programming is a bit old, but afair, CS operations are slightly expensive, because of system calls. Removing them should also help from that standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit in the assumption space but:

The rate you are talking about is set in "server" and "client" via a sleep that controls the speed with which the packets are sent. This is not necessarily the rate of actual transmission, as the OS can schedule your processes in a very asymmetric way (time wise).

This can mean that when the server gets more time, it will fill an OS buffer with packets (the client will get less processor time, thus, consumming at a lower rate => slowing down the meter). Then, when the client gets more time that the server, it will consume fast all packets, while the update thread will still do some waiting. But this doesn't mean it will "snap", because you are using a critical section to lock the packet update, so probably you don't get to consume too many packages from the OS buffer until a new update. (you may have a "snap to", but with a small step). I am basing this on the fact that i see no actual sleeping in your receive or update methods (the only sleep is done on server side).

Comment: Thanks, your observations seem to explain the behavior. Thanks for looking at the problem at a high level. Can you suggest a proper fix for when the OS schedules as it pleases? I usually send and receive on the same PC, but I may use separate PCs at times.

Comment: Depends what you want to happen. You want all the values (and a smooth movement of the meter)?. You want fidelity (snap to newest).  To get the first one very simple you can notify the graphic thread of changes (trigger a draw in the near future) so every packet gets "rendered".

Comment: Thanks again. I believe my code already achieves the 'very simple' solution you suggest, and I am suffering the side-effects.